# Java/Android: How to get a spectrum of the MP3/wav file?

Tags: java, android, parsing, mp3, wav

I need to draw a spectrum of MP3 (or wav) file. I know FFT method, but I don't how to access to the content of the mp3/wav file on java/android platform. I don't know how to parse mp3/wav format... Is there a framework which can do this?

Comment: Where is the sound file that you have to access stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support in Android for directly retrieving the pcm data from an audio file. There's a nice open-source project, [ringdroid](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/), that would be a nice starting place for a roll-your-own code to read an mp3 or wav file. You can also look into including a third-party library into your code.